# Laplace transform of complementary error function using infinite series

Tags: laplace-transform

Use infinite series to derive the Laplace transform relation $L\left\{ \operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)\right\}= \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)e^{-2\sqrt{p}}$, $a>0$

Comment: The same question was retyped with clarity

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

> Use:
>
> $$\text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)=1-\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)=1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)^{1+2n}}{(1+2n)n!}$$

---

So, we get:

$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)\right]_{(\text{s})}=$$
$$\int_0^\infty\text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)e^{-\text{s}t}\space\text{d}t=\int_0^\infty\left[1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)^{1+2n}}{(1+2n)n!}\right]e^{-\text{s}t}\space\text{d}t$$
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\text{s}t}\space\text{d}t-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(1+2n)n!}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)^{1+2n}e^{-\text{s}t}\space\text{d}t$$

Now, use:

- For the left integral ($\Re[\text{s}]>0$):
  $$\int_0^\infty e^{-\text{s}t}\space\text{d}t=\mathcal{L}_t\left[1\right]_{(\text{s})}=\frac{1}{\text{s}}$$
- For the right integral ($\Re[\text{s}]>0$):
  $$\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)^{1+2n}e^{-\text{s}t}\space\text{d}t=\text{s}^{n-\frac{1}{2}}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Michael Hardy for your answer. Sir, please note that the question is to find the Laplace transform of $erfc(1/\sqrt{t})$.

Comment: @VenkatesanMurugesan I'll edit my answer. And I'm Jan Eerland, not the other person you speak to..... :)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Jar Eerland for your timely reply.

Comment: Sir, I have  used the result as suggested by you. But I didn't get the required result. Please help if possible.

Comment: @VenkatesanMurugesan I can see what I can do